# Search text on website HTML page

Tags: javascript, search

Is there any javascript code where I can use search form to search on website html pages. I want to search all the static text that I have on my html pages, which should exclude html tags and php code etc. Search result should show with the page link and searched text.

Comment: Have you checked out [`Window.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find)? I found an example [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm). Maybe you can start with that.

Comment: If you are talking about searching files on your file system, you cannot use browser JavaScript. You may want to check out [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/). It may be able to access files by using [`fs.open(path, flags[, mode], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript runs in client's browser so, with JavaScript, you can only search in the HTML of currently displayed page and other html pages on the server can not be accessible with JavaScript.

Comment: Any script which might not be javascript but able to search text from html files on my webserver